# php with Nested JSON

Tags: php, json, nested

These Items should be put together into a JSON variable, including shop details:

```
{
"Name": "Shop 1",
"Time": "2015-12-01 12:50",
"Items": [
    {
    "Name": "Item-1",
    "Count": "4",
    "Charge": "100"
    },
    {
    "Name": "Item-3",
    "Count": "4",
    "Charge": "100"
    }
    ],
"Total": "800"
}
```

To get the outer JSON part I use:

```
class PrintData {
    public $Name = "";
    public $Time = "";
    // ??   
    public $Total = "";
}

$printdata = new PrintData();
$printdata->Name=$shop_name;
$printdata->Time=$os_tsready;
// ??  $printdata->Item=$printitems;
$printdata->Total=1007;
```

However, I cannot figure out how I can get the two Item lines into JSON.

```
foreach($orderrecords as $or) {
    $o_name=escape($or->o_name);
        $o_cout=escape($or->o_count);
        $o_charge=escape($or->o_charge);
```

How can I add the Item records correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class PrintData {
    public $Name = "";
    public $Time = "";
    public $Items = [];
    public $Total = "";
}

$printdata = new PrintData();
$printdata->Name=$shop_name;
$printdata->Time=$os_tsready;
$printdata->Items=$printitems;
$printdata->Total=1007;
```

Where `$printitems` is an array of `$item` elements (like below)

And individually,

```
$item = array(
    "Name" => "Item-1",
    "Count" => "4",
    "Charge" => "100"
);
$printdata->Items[0] = $item;
```

Online code: https://3v4l.org/R4s2C

Comment: I tried this code. I use `$printitems->Items[] = $item`, that way it fills all items, but it compiles it as: `"Items":{"Items":[{"Name":"`....  with `{"Items":` too much in the code.

Comment: Here, see this link https://3v4l.org/R4s2C (working code in an online php evaluator)

Answer (score 0):

Fully OOP approach:

```
class Item {
  public $Name;
  public $Count;
  public $Charge;

  public function __construct($name, $count, $charge) {
    $this->Name = $name;
    $this->Count = $count;
    $this->Charge = $charge;
  }
}

class PrintData {
  public $Items;
  public $Name;
  public $Time;
  public $Total;

  public function __construct($name, $time, $items, $total) {
    $this->Name = $name;
    $this->Time = $time;
    $this->Total = $total;
    $this->Items = $items;
  }
}

$res = new PrintData(
  "Shop 1",
  "2015-12-01 12:50",
  array(
    new Item("Item-1", "4", "100"),
    new Item("Item-3", "4", "100"),
  ),
  "800"
);

echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score -1):

`$printitems` should be an array here.

```
$printitems = array(
    array('Name' => 'Item-1', 'Count' => '4', 'Charge' => '100'), 
    array('Name' => 'Item-3', 'Count' => '4', 'Charge' => '100')
);
```

**Final Code**

```
<?php

class PrintData {
    public $Name = "";
    public $Time = "";
    // ??   
    public $Total = "";
}

$printdata = new PrintData();
$printdata->Name= 'Shop 1';
$printdata->Time='2015-12-01 12:50';
// ??  $printdata->Item=$printitems;
$printdata->Total='800';

$printitems = array(
    array('Name' => 'Item-1', 'Count' => '4', 'Charge' => '100'), 
    array('Name' => 'Item-3', 'Count' => '4', 'Charge' => '100')
);

$printdata->Item = $printitems;

echo '<pre>';
// TILL NOW $printdata is an Object
// json_encode() converts $printdata into JSON Object
print_r(json_encode($printdata)); // THIS WILL GIVE YOUR DESIRED RESULT
```